# Prove that the following quadratic form is positive semi-definite. (Simplification)

Tags: linear-algebra

The quadratic form that was given is below:

$$n\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2 - (\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i)^2  \quad (1)$$

So far, I've simplified it to

$$(n-1)x_1^2 - 2x_1x_2 - ... - 2x_1x_n \\
    + (n-1)x_2^2 - 2x_2x_3 - ... - 2x_2x_n\\
    + ... \\
    + (n-1)x_n^2 \quad (2)$$

which I know is equal to the following:

$$\sum_{1 \leq i< j\leq n}^{n} (x_i - x_j)^2 \quad (3)$$

I can see how they're all equivalent, but how would one take the steps to simplify from (2) to (3)? What kind of intuition or techniques are involved?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is as follows. We can write
$$
\begin{align}
n\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2 - \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i\right)^2 &= 
n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \sum_{i,j=1}^n x_ix_j
= n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \sum_{i\neq j}^n x_ix_j
\\ & = (n-1)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - 2\sum_{i< j}^n x_ix_j
\\ & = \left(\sum_{i<j} x_i^2 + x_j^2\right) - 2\sum_{i< j}^n x_ix_j
\\ & = \sum_{i<j} (x_i^2 - 2x_ix_j + x_j^2) = \sum_{i<j}(x_i - x_j)^2.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

one could also notice this is an immediate consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz, i.e.

$\big(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i\big)^2$
$=\big(\mathbf 1^T \mathbf x\big)^2$
$\leq \big \Vert \mathbf 1 \big \Vert_2^2 \cdot \big \Vert \mathbf x \big \Vert_2^2 $
$=n\cdot \sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2$

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe all the coefficients of the cross terms $x_i x_j$ should be negative, not positive. For each of the cross-terms, we know that we can complete a square if we add $x_i^2 + x_j^2$. Fortunately, these terms are provided for us! In fact, we can count how many $x_i^2$ we will need to complete every cross-term to a square. (Completing the square is often an important strategy for solving these types of problems.)

Each cross term $-2 x_i x_j$ appears exactly once, for all $1 \leq i \neq j \leq n$. We can further observe that the number of cross-terms involving $x_i$ is exactly $n - 1$: one for each cross term $x_i x_j$ where $j \neq i$. Since we are provided exactly $n - 1$ copies of $x_i^2$ in expression $(2)$, we can conclude that $(2)$ can be equated to expression $(3)$.

Comment: Right, thanks. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

$$ S=n\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2 - (\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i)^2   \tag 1$$
$$ S = \sum_{j= 1}^{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2 - \sum_{j= 1}^{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_ix_j   $$

$$ S = \sum_{j= 1}^{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i(x_i-x_j)   $$
by symmetry ...
$$ S = \sum_{j= 1}^{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_j(x_j-x_i)   $$
so 
$$ S = \frac 12\sum_{j= 1}^{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_i-x_j)(x_i-x_j)   $$
which is a symmetric form of what you had.